# Excel opens all files in directory

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2011

Excel 2011 is behaving strange. When I open a file, Excel responds by opening all (.xlsx and .csv) files in the directory!

I'm running OS X Mavericks. Tried several ways of opening: double click, right-click menu. Result is always the same: all files are opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to Excel Preferences -> General.
- Ensure "At Start-up, open all files in:" is deselected and/or blank.

If it still does it, perhaps create a new empty directory and point that above path to it.

Comment: That did the trick; removed entry after "At start-up, open all files in:".